# A simple DLL using VS2010 MFC + a test app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc

I am trying to build a very simple DLL file which supports MFC.
I use VS2010.

All the examples I found on the net shows how to export class function members.

But my client, at the end, should be a **C program**. Meaning, it doesn't know to use classes and objects.
I just need to export some simple functions for it.

What I did until now is to put the following on my dll cpp file:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) CString SayHello (CString strName){
    return theApp.SayHello(strName);
}
```

and on the app class I wrote:

```
CString CMyDLLApp::SayHello(CString strName){
    return (CString)"Hello " + strName; 
}
```

I created a simple dialog based app, which was suppose to use this function like this

```
CString strResult = SayHello(m_edit);
```

After I included the DLL h file at the top of the file:

```
#include "..\MyDll\MyDll.h"
```

But the compiler says : error C3861: 'SayHello': identifier not found

Can you please guide me how to do it? Don't offer me to not to use MFC on my DLL because I want to use the DB classes of it.

Also, how to tests it? I don't care if the test program itself is MFC based as well.

Comment: You need to include the DLL in the project, and import classes for it. MS has a tutorial for that. Just google "C++ using DLL"

Comment: I hope your **C Program** isn't going to try and consume that function that returns a `CString`.

Comment: Thanks guys.Moo, no it doesn't/

Comment: Moo, no it does't :-) I am just in the stage of trying to understand the concept.

Comment: Pawel, again, for a C client program, I think I don't nor can't import classes... can you explain please? Also, is there a complete tutorial for my needs? Thanks

Comment: In addition to `#include`'ing the header, you also need to import the `lib`. Easiest way is to add `#pragma comment(lib, "MyDll.lib")` in the same place you do the include.

Answer (score 0):

Try this declaration in your app to get rid of the compiler error:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) CString SayHello (CString strName);
```

But you cannot get theApp directly from within the DLL. Add another DLL function to pass a pointer to theApp to the DLL.